# Mod rewrite is creating duplicate links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I have URL on my site like `http://costcut.in/view-store.php?id=2` (Link 1)
I want to change it to `http://costcut.in/2` (Link 2)

I have used the following lines in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)$ view-store.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now I am able to access both Link1 and Link2 But I want the url Link 1 to be redirected to Link 2

How can I change the links from homepage and other pages to point to Link 2 instead of Link 1?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to work on raw request for that to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /view-store\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ view-store.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It has helped @hjpotter92 . I would like to know if I want to change the entire site URL from current one (costcut.in/2) to constcut.in/cash-backstore/storename

Basically I want to change the store id with the store name. Could you be able to help?

Comment: That is known as slugs. You'll have to do a lot more than `htaccess` rewrites/redirects.

Comment: I managed to get it done. However when it comes a combination of words I fails.

if store name is single, it works. But when it is combination of two space is not rendering corectly

site.com/cashback-store/storename works fine
but when it is site.com/cashback-store/store name it is not working!!

Is there any way to get rid of spaces in url with the help of mod rewrite?
@hjpotter92

Comment: Thanks for the link @hjpotter92. However I have tried it earlier and didn't work
Can you have a look into mysite now costcut.in
I have changed the urls to costcut.in/cashback-store/storename

But when the store name is like two or three words, it is not working

for eg : http://costcut.in/view-store.php?id=make my trip   the URL rewritten will be like http://costcut.in/cashback-store/make%20my%20trip

I want to replace %20 with hyphen
Current .htaccess code is 
`code` RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /?cashback-store/(.*)/?$ view-store.php?id=$1 `code`